# Java Multiple Sounds

Tags: java, audio

I'm working on a Java RPG. And now I want to play background music and other sounds when needed. For example a door opening sound.
How can I play the background music always and sometime the sounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenAL is probably what you are looking for. Bindings are provided by several projects like:[JOAL](https://jogamp.org/joal/www/) and [the Light Weight Java Game Library](http://lwjgl.org/).